# Name conflicts between Django apps

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Short question... I've written my own Django app called cms (a long time ago), and now we would like to start using django-cms. The problem is that django-cms also lives in the cms namespace (e.g. the tables start with `cms_`).  There is at least one table (`cms_page`) that both apps use.

Is there any way to get this to work that doesn't involve renaming one of the apps..?

Comment: Do not import using `from module import *` and specify namespace all the time instead?

Comment: If you've got control of the source for one of the apps, you could change the database table names manually in the model.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.db_table

Comment: @Qiau The problem is that the database tables created by both apps start with `cms_`, so even if I can solve the Python imports, there would still be name clashes in the database...

Comment: Sounds easiest to change the name of your own app.

Comment: @thebjorn: I see. Then it sounds like changing name of your own app is the easiest way like deadly said :/

Comment: @deadly that's what I'm afraid of. Changing the name of the django-cms app, or just the database table names like @AustinPhillips suggests, would probably fail when upgrading...  I was hoping Django had something similar to Python's `import cms as djangocms`.